# How can I keep numbers in memory in a calculator app?

Tags: python, pygame, calculator

I am making a calculator with a GUI but I don't know how to keep track of a number so that I can use it later on with a second number to perform an operation.

My code is as follows:

```
def Sum():
    Plus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("plus.png"))
    screen.blit(Plus,(555,34))
    c=a+b
    return c

def Sustraction():
    Minus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("minus.png"))
    screen.blit(Minus,(555,34))
    c=a-b
    return c

def Multiplication():
    Times = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("Times.png"))
    screen.blit(Times,(555,34))
    c=a*b
    return c

def Division():
    Division = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("Division.png"))
    screen.blit(Division,(555,34))
    c=a/b
    return c

def button (msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None ):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

if (x+w > mouse[0] > x) and (y+h > mouse[1] > y):
    pygame.draw.rect(CALCULATOR, WHITE, (x, y, w, h))
    if (click[0] == 1 and action != None):
        if (action == "Sum"):
            Sum()
        elif  (action == "Substraction"):
            Substraction()
        elif  (action == "Multiplication"):
            Multiplication()
        elif  (action == "Division"):
            Division()

        if  (action == "One"):
            One()
            a=1
            return a

        elif  (action == "Two"):
            Two()
            a=2
            return a

        elif  (action == "Three"):
            Three()
            a=3
            return a
```

So as you can see in my functions definition, when I call `Sum` I use `c=a+b`. The problem is I don't know how to keep `a` in memory to use it for the sum operation with `b`, because of this I don't know how to input a new value and save it in `b`.

How can I store the value of `a` while having the user input a new value into `b`?

Comment: First of all, all your operation functions should be parametrized e.g. `def Sum(a,b): .... ; c= a+b; return a+b`. This way you can then use multiple values of a, b variables. Also in your code you should first define action to do, then set variables a,b etc. and **after that** call `Sum(a,b)` or `Substraction(a,b)` or  `Multiplication(a,b)` or any other operation basing on action.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to use  [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

If its about your question. Simply use functions parameters.
Example with sum function:

```
def Sum(a, b):
    Plus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("plus.png"))
    screen.blit(Plus,(555,34))
    c=a+b
    return c
```

If you want to do it in "real time" you can use only 1 parameter and keep result as class member.

```
def Sum(a):
    Plus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("plus.png"))
    screen.blit(Plus,(555,34))
    self.result += a
```

If it does not suffice read about [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

Comment: I don't see how the postfix notation is related.

Comment: Well what I mean is reversing infix expression and store it as postfix so u dont do any operations before pressing "=" button.

Answer (score 0):

> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are
>   implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within
>   the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly
>   declared as global.
>   - [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Therefore when you assign a variable `a` and `c` in the function, it is created as a local variable. If you would try to use it before assignment, as example:

```
def increment():
    c += 1
    return c
```

you would get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment` exception.

I think in your example you would also get a `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` exception if you would call `Sum()` before `button()` callback is executed, as `a` is not yet defined. That is because `a` is referenced in the function, but not assigned - therefore is not created as a local variable, however it is also not to be found anywhere in global namespace.

The easiest solution would be to use *global* variables. Not that whenever you want to use global variable instead of creating a local one, you need to show it in the local context with the `global` keyword:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

def sum():
    global a, b
    Plus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("plus.png"))
    screen.blit(Plus,(555,34))
    c = a + b
    return c

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    global a

    if ....
```

However I would suggest using class and store values as a properties, as example:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x = 0
        self.result = 0

        self.screen = ...  # Your initialization

        self.actions = {
            "Sum": self.sum,
            "Substraction": self.subtract,
            "Multiplication": self.multiply,
            "Division": self.divide
        }
        self.numbers = {
            "One": 1,
            "Two": 2,
            "Three": 3
        }

    def sum(self, x):
        plus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("plus.png"))
        self.screen.blit(plus, (555, 34))
        self.result += x

    def subtract(self, x):
        minus = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("minus.png"))
        self.screen.blit(minus, (555, 34))
        self.result -= x

    def multiply(self, x):
        times = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("Times.png"))
        self.screen.blit(times, (555, 34))
        self.result *= x

    def divide(self, x):
        division = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("Times.png"))
        self.screen.blit(division, (555, 34))
        if x != 0:
            self.result /= x
        else:
            print("I refuse to divide by 0.")

    def button(self, msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if ((x + w) > mouse[0] > x) and ((y + h) > mouse[1] > y):
            pygame.draw.rect(CALCULATOR, WHITE, (x, y, w, h))

            if (click[0] == 1) and (action is not None):
                if action in self.actions:
                    self.actions[action]()
                elif action in self.numbers:
                    self.x = self.numbers[action]
```

In this example I also used [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict) keyword and dictionary of values, which simplify selection instead of using bunch of `if`-`elif` cases.